# Finding the value of k when the normal to the curve is parallel to the given line

Tags: derivatives

The normal to the curve $\ y=2x^2+kx-3$ at the point $(3, -6)$ is parallel to the line $x+5y=10$.

- Find the value of $k$.
- Find the coordinates of the point where the normal meets the curve again.

I am trying to find the value of $k$ but my answer is not the same as the displayed one. Firstly, I find the gradient of the curve and of the line and equal them but the answer is not right.

From my answers, the gradient of the curve is $12+k$ and the gradient of the line is $-1\over 5$. I made the two equations equal to find k but the answer is different. It said the answer for k is $-7$. Mine is $-61\over 5$.

Comment: What is your answer and how did you get it?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933)

Comment: Line is parallel to normal to the curve, then gradient of curve is not equal to gradient of the line

Comment: Are the gradients of the curve and the line not the same?

Comment: Please rephrase your title so that it is more descriptive of your question

Comment: @Kyooo The normal to the curve is perpendicular to the curve, by definition. As such, if the gradient of the normal to the curve is $m$, the gradient of the tangent to the curve is $-\frac{1}{m}$.

Comment: Ahhh I get it! It has to be $ {-1\over (12+k)} = {-1\over 5} $ instead of $(12+k) = {-1\over 5}$!

Comment: Thank you so much! I forget to do the reciprocal of the gradient value!!!!